# Phonegap Build iOS camera.getPicture() quality parameter not working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have written a Phonegap application and compiled it using the Build service.
My application calls the camera in this block of code:

function capturePhoto() {

```
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image 
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
              quality: 20,
              destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });

    }
```

The resulting image is uploaded to a server via ajax.
When I review the uploaded images, some arrive with their quality reduced appropriately but some arrive with a filesize of ~4 MB.  I have realized that users who are running my app on iPhone 4 and 5 (I have no testers with 6 yet) are consistently uploading the large images.

I have reduced quality to 10 and 5.  Image size of Android-submitted images are appropriately reduced- but still IOS images are large.  Can anyone tell me if there is a known issue here?

The API Docs say that you cannot reduce quality of images selected from gallery or camera roll- but these are not.  They are loaded from camera.

Comment: maybe because iphone ueses png ? I have no idea how phonegap implements camera but ios native uses png by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code the plugin uses for processing the image after taking the picture:

```
- (NSData*)processImage:(UIImage*)image info:(NSDictionary*)info options:(CDVPictureOptions*)options
{
    NSData* data = nil;

    switch (options.encodingType) {
        case EncodingTypePNG:
            data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            break;
        case EncodingTypeJPEG:
        {
            if ((options.allowsEditing == NO) && (options.targetSize.width <= 0) && (options.targetSize.height <= 0) && (options.correctOrientation == NO)){
                // use image unedited as requested , don't resize
                data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
            } else {
                if (options.usesGeolocation) {
                    NSDictionary* controllerMetadata = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata"];
                    if (controllerMetadata) {
                        self.data = data;
                        self.metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                        NSMutableDictionary* EXIFDictionary = [[controllerMetadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy];
                        if (EXIFDictionary) {
                            [self.metadata setObject:EXIFDictionary forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
                        }

                        if (IsAtLeastiOSVersion(@"8.0")) {
                            [[self locationManager] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"requestWhenInUseAuthorization") withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
                        }
                        [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
                    }
                } else {
                    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, [options.quality floatValue] / 100.0f);
                }
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    };

    return data;
}
```

So, if `options.encodingType` is PNG the image quality isn't change. The default value is JPG, so the problem isn't there.

But then check the

```
if ((options.allowsEditing == NO) && (options.targetSize.width <= 0) && (options.targetSize.height <= 0) && (options.correctOrientation == NO))
```

`allowsEditing` is NO by default

`targetSize.width` and `targetSize.height` are 0 by default

`correctOrientation` is NO by default

So all the conditions of the if are meet, and no change in quality is done.

It sounds like a bug as it isn't mentioned anywhere that you have to specify any other value to make the quality param work.

So, what can you do now?

You can file an issue on the cordova jira page https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB
And/or you can pass any param to change the default value and make the code to skip the if and go to the else with the quality code. Changing any of this should work:

```
  allowEdit : true,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  correctOrientation: true
```

EDIT: there is already a bug open 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6190

EDIT 2: I fixed the issue, you can get the changes with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera` or wait until it's released to NPM

Comment: the detailed analysis here really helped.

Comment: @scottdickerson I fixed the plugin and it was released some weeks ago, you shouldn't have this problem anymore if you use the latest version of the plugin

Comment: Oh, I remember now, it was released but "latest" still points to the old version due to some problems on visual studio, to install the version with the fix do ```cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera@2```

Comment: hey i'm still having that problem today. is this ok?

var options = {
   quality: 25,
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
   sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
   encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
   correctOrientation: true,
   allowEdit: false,
   targetHeight: 200,
   targetwidth: 200
     };

Comment: @BraianMellor which plugin version are you using? you might be using an old version, or the bug might be back.

Comment: cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.0 "Camera"

Comment: and some times camera is not showing and get this at xcode console: Warning: Attempt to present <CDVCameraPicker: 0x138111400>  on <MainViewController: 0x137e09640> which is already presenting <ForcedViewController: 0x137e9a560>

Comment: The second error looks like a problem with an old version of cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue. iOS has larger pictures. They call it a feature.

http://lifeinlofi.com/more/iphone-photo-sizes-2007-2013/

Jesse