# How can I make iPhone respect Phonegap Camera quality setting?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, camera

I am using Cordova 5.0 with the built in Camera plugin. My application requires uploading photos taken to a remote server, so I need to constrain the size of the files phone-side for bandwidth and performance reasons.

I am using the following camera options for capturing new photos:

```
capturePhoto: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function (imageData) {
            this.setState({ imageData: imageData });
            this.props.onCapture(imageData);
        }.bind(this),
        handleError,
        {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            quality: 20
        }
    );
},
```

This works fine on many devices, a 3000x2000 pixel image from an Android phone taking around 160K on disk. However on some iPhone 5s, the quality parameter appears to be ignored, resulting in imageData being 9M as base64, 6M as binary. Using `identify` on the resultant file indicated Quality is 100.

The only solution I can think of is to constrain the image size rather than quality with `targetHeight` and `targetWidth`, but is there a way to cause iOS devices to respect the `quality` parameter?

Comment: You can set different [ cameraOptions ] for different platform. Check device.platform and set [ cameraOptions ] accordingly.

Comment: It's a bug on the camera code, see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252483/phonegap-build-ios-camera-getpicture-quality-parameter-not-working/31262295#31262295, there is already an issue open for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6190 and I have already sent a pull request, you can use my code until they merge https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/108