# Getting ’getPicture not responding while integrating cordova camera plug in

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I tried the below steps:

1. I installed the Cordova plugin and run this command in the terminal

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera.
2. I added the plugin name in `config.xml`

Add `<feature>` like this:

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
```

3. In JavaScript, I called the plugin like this:

   Picture
       
           
           
               document.addEventListener('deviceready', function()  {alert('device ready');} , false);
               function getPicture() {
                   navigator.camera.getPicture{
                       function(imageURL){
                           var image=document.getElementById('takePicture');
                           image.src=FILE_URI;
                       },
                       function(message){
                           alert('faild because :' + message);

   ```
                   },
                   {
                       quality:50,
                       destinationType:camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                   }
               };  
           }
       </script>
   ```

But while running, I got the error: `getPicture not responding`

These are my specs:

- Cordova 6.0.0
- iOS  OS 10.11.1
- Xcode 7.2

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This link might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252483/phonegap-build-ios-camera-getpicture-quality-parameter-not-working?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova ios camera plug in integration error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341837/cordova-ios-camera-plug-in-integration-error)